# Dynamic Array in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have been looking around for a while trying to under stand how to have a class, then how to also have a dynamic array in it.

I am trying to build a bank account c++ program that will make a unlimited number of accounts (memory is the only limit), so i want a dynamic array, where say, p[1] is the first account then p[2] is the second account and and to have it be a member of the bankAccount class. So that i can have the array at memory location 1, aka account number 1, and then also have other info like first last name, balance and etc associated with it. maybe something like if i have array p[] in class bankAccount,then i can use p[1].name.

I am new to this site, if there are better ways to ask questions or post code examples, please feel free to tell me.

This is the main part that i am having trouble with, declaring the dynamic array as a member of the class:

```
class bankAccount
{
    int i;
    int index;
    int AccountNum;
    double balance;
    string last;
    string first;
public:
    void intro();
    void deposit();
    void withdraw();
    void newAcc ();
    void editAcc();
    void chgAcc();
    void print();
    bankAccount::bankAccount();
}p [10]; // This is what i want to be dynamic
```

Thank you.

Comment: With all due respect, you have to format ur code before anyone can even consider it as a question. and please post only the part which explains your issue.

Comment: the code you posted cannot compile, please post the exact code you are having the problem with. the `bankAccount::bankAccount();` statement in main (at least) is invalid.

Comment: I think i edited my answer more to your format, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the data structure that you are looking for is [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/). A `std::vector` is basically a dynamic array under the hood but everything is managed for you.

I would actually go so far as to say that you should never use a dynamic array in C++, it is what I would class as a C concept that has been superseded. (All rules have their exceptions, but what I mean is that unless you ***know*** why you are choosing a dynamic array over a `vector`, then you should choose a `vector`.

Comment: So then how would i add use the vector, like where would i put it into my code?

Comment: Check out the link above and read up on them, hopefully that will make it clear. They are the bread and butter of C++ programmers, you should take some time to find out about them and then hopefully it will be obvious how to use them.

Comment: Ok, I looked up and read about vectors, i have the "C++ Programming, program design including data structures, 5th edition" But i don;t know how i can us it with my class bankAccount, I want the vector to hold the hold the account numbers, and then if i go to that number i can access the information assoiated with that account number.  Can i make the vector array, a member of the class?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to implement dynamic array by yourself, looking at this piece of code:

```
 bankAccount *p;
```

C++ STL already has dynamic array implemented, which is [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

Answer (score 0):

You allocated backAccount[i] when I was 1.  When you create a new account you would need to free this are reallocate.  Also you life will be allot easier if you sue std::vector.